# Pop up menu is hidden behind dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dialog that contains a gridview where the user can enter in information. 
One of the textboxes for the grid has a button next to it. When this button is clicked it pop ups a menu with a list of items and the user can choose one and it populates the textbox. 
The problem is the pop up menu is showing behind the dialog box so I can see all of it. I need to pop up to show in front of the dialog box.

Code for the dialog box:

```
$("#manifestEdit").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 510,
            width: 910,
            modal: false,
            buttons: {

            }
 close: function () {
            }
        });
```

Code for the pop up menu:

```
<div id="divPickList<%= this.ClientID %>" class="dvdraggable dvAddressList" style="min-width:410px;">
    <table id="Table1">
        <tr >
            <td id="tdSearchHeaderCost" runat="server" class="tdPreviewHeader" >
                Part List
                <a onclick="HidePickList<%= this.ClientID %>()" title="Close" class="previewClose"></a>
                <a href="Stock.aspx" target="_blank" title="Add new Part..." class="btnNewAddress" id="btnNewLookupCost" style="float:right;"></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>                                                      
            <td class="tableSearchHeader" ><input class="SearchBox" type"text" id="txtAddressSearchOption<%= this.ClientID %>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="replacerow">
            <td>
                <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>                                             
</div>
```

When the button next to the textbox is clicked this code runs to show the pop up:

```
 $("#divPickList<%= this.ClientID %>").fadeIn(300);
 $("#divPickList<%= this.ClientID %>").offset({ top: 300, left: 300 });
```

Is there something I need to add here so the pop up shows in front of the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `z-index` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

you just need to set the `z-index` to something higher than your dialog.

`<div id="divPickList<%= this.ClientID %>" style="z-index: 99" ...`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#manifestEdit").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        modal: false
      });
               
      $("#divPickList").fadeIn(300);
      $("#divPickList").offset({
        top: 140,
        left: 100
      });
    });
```

```css
#manifestEdit
{
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1
}

#divPickList
{
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="manifestEdit">
  The Manifest!
</div>

<div id="divPickList" class="dvdraggable dvAddressList" style="min-width:410px;">
  <table id="Table1">
    <tr>
      <td id="tdSearchHeaderCost" runat="server" class="tdPreviewHeader">
        Part List
        <a onclick="HidePickList()" title="Close" class="previewClose"></a>
        <a href="Stock.aspx" target="_blank" title="Add new Part..." class="btnNewAddress" id="btnNewLookupCost" style="float:right;"></a>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableSearchHeader">
        <input class="SearchBox" type "text" id="txtAddressSearchOption" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="replacerow">
      <td>
        <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Pop up is still showing behind the dialog

Comment: @user123456789 I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working. I've added a code snippet to give an example. Is your textbox even fading in properly? I noticed that your jquery selector is `$("#divPickList<%= this.ClientID %>")`, and the part between brackets `<%= this.ClientID %>` is razor syntax and will be replaced by the server with the value of this.ClientID. Are you generating your javascript with razor as well? If not, then your jquery selector won't work as written.